# Generating if statement JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have an array `selected_filters` which I fill with id of clicked element. I need to generate an `if` statement according to this array. I tried to generate string and then use `eval()` to execute it, but didn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or do you have any ideas how to generate statement?

Statement string generation:

```
 var selected_filters = [filter_by_color,filter_by_transmissivity];
    $.each(selected_filters, function(k, v){
      validate += '($.inArray(t.data(' + v + '),filters_obj[' + v + ']) > -1 || obj_l == emptyFilters) && '; 
    });
    validate += '(search.contains(filters_obj.search) || filters_obj.search.length === 0)';
```

Generated string:
`($.inArray(t.data(filter_by_color),filters_obj[filter_by_color]) > -1 || obj_l == emptyFilters) && ($.inArray(t.data(filter_by_transmissivity),filters_obj[filter_by_transmissivity]) > -1 || obj_l == emptyFilters) && (search.contains(filters_obj.search) || filters_obj.search.length === 0)`

Usage:

```
if(eval(validate)){ //some code }
```

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? Code is not executed? Do you see any error?

Comment: Code  always inside `else` condition. But I have many cases which are `true` for `if`

Comment: The only thing I can recommend is to find a situation when behavior is incorrect, get generated if statement replace `if(eval(validate))` with generated condition and debug.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. Changed logic and don't use `eval()` anymore.
Changed code to:

```
var visible = true;
 $.each(selected_filters, function(k, v){
  visible = visible && ($.inArray(t.data(v),filters_obj[v]) > -1 || filters_obj[v].length === 0);
                });
  visible = visible && (search.contains(filters_obj.search) || filters_obj.search.length === 0);
```

Usage:
`if(visible){ //some code }`